# R Differential Optimization produces error in checkForRemoteErrors(val): 4 nodes produced errors;

Tags: r, parallel-processing, caret, particle-swarm

I am trying to use DEOptim package to tune gradient boosting (gbm) with caret. When I launch the job, I have an error: `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val): 4 nodes produced errors; first error: Stopping`

I am working with R version 4.2.0 with Linux Centos 7.
May be I am doing something wrong in my code or with with cores + R.
tune parameters:
`n.trees, interaction_min_max,shrinkage,minobsinnode`

I provide few lines of my code:

```
library(caret)
library(DEoptim)
library(parallel)


fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",number = 5,repeats = 3)

#Differential
# Set parameter settings for search algorithm
max_iter <- 5 # maximum number of iterations
pop_size <- 10 # population size

# Create custom function for assessing solutions
eval_function_XGBoost_Linear <- function(x, data, train_settings) {
  
  x1 <- x[1]; x2 <- x[2]; x3 <- x[3]; x4 <- x[4]
  
suppressWarnings(
  XGBoost_Linear_model <- caret::train(isMut ~., 
                          data = data,
                          method = "gbm",
                          trControl = train_settings,
                          verbose = FALSE, 
                          silent = 1,
                          tuneGrid = expand.grid(
                                                interaction.depth = x1,
                                                n.trees = x2, 
                                                shrinkage = x3, 
                                                n.minobsinnode = x4 
                                                ) 
                          )
)

    return(XGBoost_Linear_model$results$Accuracy) # Accuracy

}
```

I Define minimum and maximum values for each input

```
interaction_min_max <- c(1,9)
ntrees_min_max <- c(1500,2000)
shrinkage <- c(0.1,0.1)
minobsinnode <- c(20,20)
```

When I run the differential evolution algorithm, I have the error described above.

```
set.seed(1)
n_cores <- detectCores()-1
​
DE_T0 <- Sys.time()
# Run differential evolution algorithm
DE_model_XGBoost_Linear <- DEoptim::DEoptim(
  fn = eval_function_XGBoost_Linear, 
  lower = c(interaction_min_max[1], ntrees_min_max[1], shrinkage[1], minobsinnode[1]),
  upper = c(interaction_min_max[2], ntrees_min_max[2], shrinkage[2], minobsinnode[2]), 
  control = DEoptim.control(
                            NP = pop_size, # population size
                            itermax = max_iter, # maximum number of iterations
                            CR = 0.5, # probability of crossover
                            storepopfreq = 1, # store every population
                            parallelType = 1 # run parallel processing
                            ),
  data = rose,
  train_settings = fitControl
  )

DE_T1 <- Sys.time()
DE_T1-DE_T0
```

Comment: For troubleshooting, try with `library(doFuture); registerDoFuture(); plan(multisession, workers = 2)` and then use `parallelType = 2` (IMPORTANT) instead.  That should give you a more informative error message.

Comment: BTW, have you verified that it works in sequential mode, i.e. with `parallelType = 0`?

Comment: @HenrikB, yes i have already tried with ˋparellelType=0‘ and it does not work. I have another error message saying something wrong with accuracy.  Which weird the same code works with no error on another computer with an older version of R (3.6.0)
I have not try your lines above yet. Keep you inform.

Comment: in sequential mode (`parallelType=0`), I have: `Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  ...`

Comment: If so, I'll focus on troubleshooting with `parallelType = 0`, and only when that is fixed worry about parallelization.

Comment: @HenrikB, I actually did a new test. Instead passing the dataset generated by ROSE Library in order to deal with imbalance dataset, i used directly training and the error disappears. Maybe there is a bug when we use dataset generated by ROSE LIBRARY.